# Create array of data with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to create an array from a loop which gets data from DB using AJAX.
This is an example of the data:

```
events : [

                    {
                        id : 999,
                        title : 'Anglais Mr Azhar 2A',
                        start : '2015-12-08T14:30:00',
                        end : '2015-12-07T16:30:00'
                    },

                    {
                        id : 999,
                        title : 'ERP 1B',
                        start : '2015-12-08T16:45:00',
                        end : '2015-12-08T18:15:00'
                    },

                    {
                        id : 999,
                        title : 'PMC Mr Belasla 3A',
                        start : '2015-12-07T08:30:00',
                        end : '2015-12-07T10:00:00'
                    },
]
```

I want to assign the array created in the loop to `events` not like in this example where it is done manually.

So how can I create an Array from this data--id, title, start, ...--
to set events?
Something like this:

```
events=myArray
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is boucle?

Comment: Could you try to explain your issue a bit better? I'm having trouble understanding the question as written.

Comment: @WalkerRandolphSmith i am sorry i meaned a loop

Comment: @Redmega I mean how can i create an array with id,title....

Comment: looks like you are using Full Calendar and want to make a list of dynamic events that can be rendered into the calender. Look at the docs which cover how to import events (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/)

Comment: @OmarMouçouf is the ajax call returning individual Event objects or a json array of event objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let says if you got already data that coming from ajax success, you can populate it like following :

```
// suppose you have this callback
// on ajax call
success : function ( data ) {
   // create empty array container
   var events = [];
   // loop over data
   // this depend on how the data variable
   // structure
   for ( var e in data ) {
      obj = {
         id : e.id,
         title : e.title,
         start : e.start,
         end : e.end
      }
      // add obj above into array container
      events.push( obj );
   }

}
```

Comment: if data is coming as an array of objects already you can just do `var events = data`

Comment: @Redmega Yes and not, if the data coming from ajax holding another properties other than 4 stated above, it would be wrong.

Comment: I'm assuming he's making the ajax call to a rest service specifically meant to return the `Event` objects for a particular calendar. If this is the case then the assumption that `var events = data;` is a safe one to make. If it's not, then he probably needs to ponder over the design of his web service.

Comment: @Redmega Yes, should be like that. Seems like OP did't give enough explanation though